# framework--Deployment,Configuration and continuous integration without server reboot

Tags: continuous-integration

If you wanted to a platform or framework upon which to build modular software that could be deployed and configured without full server bounces/reboots and works with continuous integration, what solution would you select, and why?

Comment: What is the technology stack that you are aiming for (java , c#) ?

Comment: technology using as java